Cutting off "deleted comment timeline"
Here is a bug with the new design. I'm in Chrome.
On a "wide enough" screen, the "deleted comment timeline" shows up like this:

If I shrink the screen enough, I get this:

However, there is a range in between the switch where the "deleted comment timeline" is cut off:


Just checked this again and it seems to be fixed.
